# .net core api hierarchical routing

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, overriding, hierarchical

I'm building an api, and I want to be able to use hierarchical routing such as:

```
api/category/1234/product
api/category/1234/product/5678
```

Currently I'm using a *Route* attribute on the **ProductController:** `[Route("api/[controller]")]` This is because most of my routing follows that convention.

I have a method on the **ProductController:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/category/{categoryId:int}/product")]
public IActionResult GetAllByCategoryId(int categoryId)
{
    var products = _productRepo.Query(p => p.CategoryId == categoryId);

    return Ok(products);
}
```

Hooray, it returns data for `api/category/{categoryId:int}/product`

but it will still return the data for `api/product/{categoryId:int}` because of the *Route* attribute on the controller.

**My question is:**

Is there a way to override the controller route template?

The only alternative option I can think of at the moment is to place a *Route* attribute on every single method. There has to be a better way to deal with hierarchical routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it will still return the data for api/product/{categoryId:int}
>   because of the Route attribute on the controller.

This is not quite right. Your `GetAllByCategoryId()` action will be accessible only by `/api/category/{categoryId:int}/product` as you specified in action-level `Route` attribute.

If you send HTTP GET for `api/product/12345` and receive some data back, probably you have some other action in the controller that processes the request. It will probably have one of the following routing attributes:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    // ...
}
```

or

```
[Route("{id:int}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    // ...
}
```

So just debug your controller and check what action is actuall executed. I bet it will not be `GetAllByCategoryId()`.

Comment: Whoops!
Thanks haha